# Add opacity .4 a class when select size and after load function opacity return 1

Tags: jquery

I need to understand how to assign css opacity .4 when a size is selected from the select and an end load of the function, the opacity returns to 1. Is it possible? Excuse my English

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(".form-control-select").on('change', null, function() {
    $('.product_middle_column').css('opacity', '.4');
  });
});
```

Comment: You can set the opacity back to `1` in the exact same way you set it to `.4`. It's not clear what you're asking, though. What does '...and an end load of the function, the opacity returns to 1.` mean?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When I select a size, the opacity 0.4 is added, but then when the select becomes effective, the opacity remains 0.4, instead I want it to become 1. Practically, when it finishes loading the function the opacity remains 0.4 while I would like it to return to 1. I hope I explained myself well